# Simplest way to split string on equal parts in Perl6

Tags: raku

Is there an elegant way in Perl6 to split a string into equal parts, as, for example, it is implemented in the PowerShell? In PowerShell:

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' -split '(.{8})'
```

Result:

```
abcdefgh
ijklmnop
qrstuvwx
yz
```

There are a lot of foolish `split` in the official documentation of Perl6 and no one simplest and effective. Suggestions?

Comment: Why do you think the provided examples in the `split` documentation are foolish? Maybe the documentation can be improved?

Comment: Any suggestion for improving the documentation will be very much welcome. Including adding a reference to comb, if needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It wouldn't be in the docs for [`.split`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/split) because it is [`.comb`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/comb) you are looking for.

```perl6
.say for 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.comb: 8
```

```
abcdefgh
ijklmnop
qrstuvwx
yz
```

It is also used to match parts of a string using a regex

```perl6
.say for 'abcdefg4444hijklmnop4444qrstuvwxyz'.comb: /..\d+../
```

```
fg4444hi
op4444qr
```

You could look at the `.comb(Int)` form as a shortcut for a regex that matches up to that number of characters

```perl6
.say for 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.comb: / . ** 1..8 /
```

```
abcdefgh
ijklmnop
qrstuvwx
yz
```

---

Technically you can use `.split`, but it is generally used for removing the splitting characters. When you ask it to keep them, it returns a [Match](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Match) object for the splitting characters.

```perl6
.say for 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split( /. ** 1..8/, :v, :skip-empty )
```

(Since the regex matches what we are looking for, `:skip-empty` is used to remove the empty unmatched strings “between” them.)

```
｢abcdefgh｣
｢ijklmnop｣
｢qrstuvwx｣
｢yz｣
```

---

It could also be done using the `:global`/`:g` option on a regex, but it also returns [Match](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Match) objects.

```perl6
.say for 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' ~~ m :global / . ** 1..8/
```

```
｢abcdefgh｣
｢ijklmnop｣
｢qrstuvwx｣
｢yz｣
```